# Microsoft Test Manager 2015

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager

Please see the picture below for reference. Does anyone know how to associate Test Runs to a PBI in TFS Microsoft Test manager. The 3 results I have circled below I had to manually associate each Test Run to the PBI. Is there a way to have them automatically link up? Test Cases automatically do this. (Tested By)
[image]

Comment: According to your screenshot , it's the PBI work item in web portal not in TFS Microsoft Test manager. And there are test results  you have circled below, also not  test runs. Did you just want to auto associate  all test results of the specific tests cases which linked to PBI?

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT  correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To associate automated test results with PBI, you could do this directly from test result page.

On the test results page, select the tests you want to link to PBI and choose the **Associate tests to work item** (link) icon.

[image]

Select the PBI from the list of suggested work items and choose Associate.

[image]